# Bottle multiple template variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

Is there any way to give the template multiple variables through bottle? i know that you can use `template('mytemplate.tpl',var=var)` and such, however, how can you use multiple variables?

Comment: I know it's been a while, but it could help for someone else. 
The official documentation: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [signature](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.template), one can pass any number of variables to the template by using [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments):

```
template('mytemplate.tpl', name="Anne", address="4 Elm Street", 
                          dob=datetime.datetime(1977,12,2,1,2,3))
```

or like this

```
d = { "name": "Anne", "address": "4 Elm Street", "dob": datetime.datetime(1977,12,2,1,2,3) }
template('mytemplate.tpl', **d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values = {'name':name, 'gender':gender, 'age':age, 'address':address} 
template('mytemplate', var = values)
```

In your template, you access the variables as `var.name`, `var.gender`, `var.age`, `var.address`

Answer (score 0):

The method which I prefer is this:

```
@route('/')
@view('mytemplate') #no .tpl
def mypage():
    return {"name": "Anne", "address": "4 Elm Street", "dob": datetime.datetime(1977,12,2,1,2,3)}
```

This makes handling multiple return statements much easier (although some people consider multiple return statements bad practice), and I find it is much easier to change the template file, as I don't need to go find it every time.

Or if you prefer the a=b, b=c, etc. method

```
return dict(name="Anne", address="4 Elm Street", dob=datetime.datetime(1977,12,2,1,2,3))
```